# Where to search?

Tags: c#, search, syntax, text-files

I am currently doing a small C# exercise that involves a text file. All the text file has are sentences for each new line in the text file. So far, I am able to read and store the text into a string array. What I need to do next, is to search for a particular term and then write out any sentences that contain the searched word/phrase. I just want to know if I should do it inside the while loop or somewhere else?

```
String filename = @"sentences.txt";


// File.OpenText allows us to read the contents of a file by establishing
// a connection to a file stream associated with the file.
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filename);

if (reader == null)
{
   // If we got here, we were unable to open the file.
   Console.WriteLine("reader is null");
   return;
 }

  // We can now read data from the file using ReadLine.

 Console.WriteLine();

 String line = reader.ReadLine();


  while (line != null)
  {

     Console.Write("\n{0}", line);
     // We can use String.Split to separate a line of data into fields.


     String[] lineArray = line.Split(' ');
     String sentenceStarter = lineArray[0];

     line = reader.ReadLine();


  }
  Console.Write("\n\nEnter a term to search and display all sentences containing it: ");
        string searchTerm = Console.ReadLine();

        String searchingLine = reader.ReadLine();


        while (searchingLine != null)
        {


            String[] lineArray = line.Split(' ');
            String name = lineArray[0];



            line = reader.ReadLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < lineArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (searchTerm == lineArray[0] || searchTerm == lineArray[i])
                {
                    Console.Write("\n{0}", searchingLine.Contains(searchTerm));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: if you got that far, the next step should not be difficult.

Comment: I know, I'm just wondering where, to search. I want to search through "lineArray" but outside the while loop I cant do it outside

Comment: do breakpoints, this happens when you copy paste code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `File` class to make things a bit easier.

To read all the lines from a text file you can use `File.ReadAllLines`

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("myTextFile.txt");
```

If you want to find all the lines that contain a word or sentance you can use `Linq`

```
// get array of lines that contain certain text.
string[] results = lines.Where(line => line.Contains("text I am looking for")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that if you're using Linq, you could use `File.ReadLines()` to avoid holding the entire file in memory: `string[] results = File.ReadLines(filename).Where(line => line.Contains("text I am looking for")).ToArray();`

Comment: No. I have done anything with LINQ. All I want to know is where to search now that I can display all the contents of the text file.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** I just want to know if I should do it inside the while loop or somewhere else?
**Answer:** If you dont want (and you should not) to store all file content in memory - inside the while loop. Otherwise you can copy every line in while loop to `List` or `array` and search inside them somewhere else (again, with large files this is very resource greedy approach and not recommended)

Personal note:
your code looks strange (especially second `while` loop - it will never execute as file is already read, you need to reset `reader` if you want to read the file again). First `while` loop is doing nothing usefull except writing to console...

If this is real code you should really consider revising it and implementing Matthew Watson's suggestion with LINQ

Comment: thank you. your suggestion fixed the problem I had. And I have fixed my while loop...

Comment: you are welcome. Dont forget to upvote and/or mark as answer useful comments on your questions (you have 4 questions so far with valuable answers but none was accepted) [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) article will provide you more info